# Change Name of Outputted DLL

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005

If my project name is ABC and the DLL currently outputs as ABC.DLL, how can I make my DLL be outputted as say CBA.DLL and so that when the .LIB is compiled linked against, it is not looking for ABC.DLL, but CBA.DLL. I tried changing the name under Linker > General > Output File but when I linked to the .lib in my other application, it was still looking for ABC.DLL and CBA.DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No repro, the .lib file has the correct DLL name.  The original name is not present at all.

But, don't make the same mistake I first made.  Use cba.lib, not abc.lib.

Comment: Hmm.. ok, well it was just easier to move to another project with the name I wanted then fiddle with it if no one else can repro.

Answer (score 1):

What you did was correct. I built a DLL in VS2005, using the name ABC, then changed the output to CBA, my bin directory contained both DLLs (even after a clean). Frag those, rebuild it, and ensure that in your main application you have removed all references to ABC.LIB/DLL and you should be good.